# Query by one meta_key and sort by another (possibly NULL value)

Tags: query, order

I want to query by 1 meta key, but sort by another key that may or may not exist, and *then* by post date

So the end result would be something like:

Meta Key A / Date 1
Meta Key A / Date 2
Meta Key B / Date 1
No Meta Key / Date 1
No Meta Key / Date 2

Query args like the following are not returning any posts:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_customer_user',
            'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_dealer_number',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_dealer_number',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND'
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value date',
    'order'      => 'ASC'
) );
```

Is this possible with `WP_Query` args or do I need to filter `posts_orderby`? If so, what might I use?

Comment: You are querying posts where `_dealer_number` exists and at same time not exists: it's pretty impossible :) Maybe using `OR` as relation may work, but I'm not sure and moreover in that case `_customer_user` becomes optional too, that doesn't seems what you want. I'm afraid you need to filter `posts_orderby`, `posts_where` and `posts_join` to obtain desired result.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that `_dealer_number` existing and not existing at the same time is impossible. :) But I still want `_customer_user` to be required at all times. Is there a way to filter `posts_orderby`, etc so that the custom orderby clause only effects this `get_posts()` query?

Comment: Yes. Set a custom flag to query `get_posts( array( 'filter_me' => TRUE` and inside the filter chek if flag exists, if not, don't filter. And when you apply the filter, immediately remove it so that it run once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it without using filters. Using `posts_clauses` you could do:

```
function wpse163696_posts_clauses( $pieces, $query ) {
    if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) != 'dealer_date' ) {
        return $pieces;
    }
    global $wpdb;

    $order = $query->get( 'order' );
    $pieces[ 'join' ] .= $wpdb->prepare(
        ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' dealer_pm ON dealer_pm.post_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID AND dealer_pm.meta_key = %s'
        , '_dealer_number' );
    $pieces[ 'orderby' ] = 'ISNULL(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value)) ' . $order . ', MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value) ' . $order  . ', ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_date ' . $order;
    return $pieces;
}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse163696_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_customer_user',
            'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'dealer_date',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
) );
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse163696_posts_clauses', 10 );
```

Comment: This is almost there! Awesome! For some reason I can't get the posts with a dealer_number key to come first no matter how I set the `orderby` parameter. Could it be something in the `fields` parameter? I don't really understand what is going on there.

Comment: It could be the fields parameter, it's assuming "_dealer_number" is numeric - is it? (All it's trying to do is negate it so that if it exists (is not NULL) it will sort before 0, ie when it doesn't exist (is NULL). There are a various other possible (probably nicer) methods.)

Comment: Actually just found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195311/664741 - much nicer solution to NULL sorting (not type dependent), will edit answer...

Comment: That works great. I had to modify it to `$pieces[ 'orderby' ] = 'ISNULL(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value)) ASC, MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value) ASC, ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_date DESC';` so that it would be alphabetized and then go by most recent posts.

Comment: seem to have hit a small hiccup. For some reason there are posts with no "dealer number" *before* the posts with dealer numbers as well as after. See this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/eVwG2ju.png) for a better idea. Any idea what is keeping it from displaying all posts with a dealer number and then all the posts where dealer number is null?

Comment: My guess is that those dealer_numbers exist but are set to a zero-length string - could this be the case? If so then changing the orderby to something like `ISNULL(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value)) OR LENGTH(TRIM(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value))) = 0 ASC` etc would cater for them.

Comment: That is probably the case. Could we treat the non-existing keys the *same* as the zero-length strings? Based on your last comment: `$pieces[ 'orderby' ] = 'ISNULL(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value)) OR LENGTH(TRIM(MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value))) = 0 ASC, MAX(dealer_pm.meta_value) ASC,' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_date DESC';` is **very** close. Posts with that meta key come alphabetized at the top, but then there still seems to be a distinction between nulls and zero-length.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, the zero-length strings are getting sorted differently before the date kicks in - perhaps then targeting the left join to product NULLs in that case - eg ... `AND dealer_pm.meta_key = %s AND LENGTH(TRIM(dealer_pm.meta_value))` would work...

Comment: I think that's it. With this in the join clause and the orderby from my previous comment, I am now getting all the null/empty meta key posts at the end of my list, and sorted by date. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors there, I believe.

1. There is no such parameter as `'numberposts'`. Perhaps you mean `'posts_per_page'`? That is what you should use to determine the number of posts to display.
2. When ordering by meta value, the correct syntax should be:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'key_name',
```

Where key_name is the custom field whose meta_value you are using for the orderby.

So based on your question, your query may look like this:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => $order_count,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key'     => '_customer_user',
        'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'compare' => '=',
      ),
      array(
        'key'     => '_dealer_number',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
      ),
      array(
        'key'     => '_dealer_number',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      ),
      'relation' => 'AND'
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'   => 'date',
    'order'      => 'ASC'
  )
);
```

(Note that I added `'no_found_rows'`. If you know how many posts you are going to query and do not need pagination, then this addition will greatly speed up your query).

Comment: According to the codex for [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)(which of course can be out of date) `numberposts` and `posts_per_page` can be used interchangeably. But that isn't the real problem. I have determined that the `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` at the same time (at least with the `AND` relation returns nothing, at least with the `AND` relation. But I don't know how to have it `AND` for the `_customer_user`. You're answer is overlooking how I would like to sort by the `_dealer_number` key which is not guaranteed to be in existence and *then* by post date.

Comment: Ah, yes, silly me, I missed that EXISTS and NOT EXISTS! Of course, you can't have something exist and not exist at the same time :) As for the orderby -- just change to 'meta_value date' (the meta_key still must exist)

Comment: Yeah I missed that too. #facepalm! Anyway, I tried your suggestion and it results in zero posts being found. See Bonger's answer... modifying the `posts_join` and `posts_orderby` clauses did it.